# Error when deleting these pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I know that when I initialize a pointer with new, that I need to delete the pointer or a memory leak will occur. I have a class that is setup as such:

```
class foobar
{
private:

    //! Pointer to the global nodal list
    int *p_test1;

    //! Pointer to the global block label list
    int *p_test2;

public:
    foobar(int *test1, int *test2)
    {
        p_test1 = test1;
        p_test2 = test2;
    }

    ~foobar()
    {
        delete p_test1;
        delete p_test2;
    }
};
```

Now, when the destructor is called, the program crashes and the console says Program exited with return code -6.

The debug window states that:

Program Received signal SIGABRT

When I got through the call stack, one of the last items is the destructor. The stack appears to attempt to free the memory but fails.

I ma wondering why this is the case? And what is the preferred method on freeing the memory with the class setup as such.

As a side note, if I comment out the code in the destructor, the pointers will of course not be freed when the instance of the foobar class is finished. However, when I call another instance of the class (say that the creation of the instance is dictated by the user pressing a button on a GUI), then the program crashes. Again, why is this? I have a feeling that this is related to not properly destroying the pointers.

Comment: Did you really allocate memeory? Where did you use new operator in your code?

Comment: using `delete` of a pointer in a destructor implies that ownership is of the object. Now we just see you are passing a pointer to the object and store it, who allocated it? Where is the related `new`?

Comment: In the code, I am calling a function that returns the pointer to the object. The object itself is NOT a pointer. The object is owned by another class. When the destructor occurs for this one, I do not want to delete the object. I just want to reset these pointers back to "zero" or delete them

Comment: Would it be better to set the pointers in the foorbar class to Null in the destructor?

Comment: Include the code that creates the pointers passed to the constructor, and the object instantiation itself

Comment: Don't describe your code in prose. Show a [mcve].

Comment: Those pointers may point to local variables of a function for example, which you cannot delete. We can only know if we see how you are creating them.

Comment: Ok sounds good but it will be a minute for me to create the minimal example

Comment: Did you initialize the pointer with new?

Comment: This is quite weird C++ code design, far from what modern C++11-after source should look. Consider not using `new/delete` at all, and if you can't avoid it (usually you should be able easily with good overall architecture), then I would rather keep the `new + delete` corresponding pairs in the same source, near each other. At this moment you have `new` who-knows-where, and `delete` here, which will make it difficult to read+review such source, having to use lot of reasoning to see if each `new` is paired with `delete` properly (obviously it is already not, as you get crashes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, there is no new in this example, so it makes it difficult to explain the balance between `new` and `delete`.

The rule is if you new a pointer you should delete it.

```
int * p = new int( 5 );

std::cout << "The value of p is " << *p << std::endl;

delete p;
```

However, if you use an object, as you didn't new it, you shouldn't (normally) delete it.

```
void somefunction( int * p )
{
    std::cout << "The value of p is " << *p << std::endl;

    delete p; // this looks smelly - deleting a pointer which was allocated.
}
```

To try and simplify this problem (which pointers should I delete), modern C++ has some good guidelines.

### Resource Acquisition Is Initialization

RAII puts resources into a class.  A full class (as opposed to a pointer), has a very clear lifecycle.  When it is destroyed because it goes out of scope, then the destructor is called.

```
 class PointerHolder {
      int * mp;
   public:
      PointerHolder( int value ) : mp( NULL) {
          mp = new int( value );
      }
      ~PointerHolder() {
          delete mp;
      }
 }
```

Although the above example breaks the rule of 5.

### Rule of 5 (or zero)

The problem with PointerHolder above, is it doesn't implement all of the 5 special operators.

```
PointerHolder a( 12 );
PointerHolder b( 10 );

a = b;  // What is going to happen?????
```

a gets the value of b's pointer, and when the second is destroyed, it is the second delete of the same piece of memory, and the program crashes.

The rule of 5 states, if you implement either the `destructor`, the `move operator`, the `copy constructor`, or `operator =` you should implement (or remove all of them).

In this case, removing the move and copy operators, would produce a simple `unique_ptr`.

The rule of zero, is that a class is more re-usable, if it implements all of the operators, or none of them.

If you need to implement only some of the operators, it is probable that you have not identified the "resource" - which should be a single class with all 5 overloaded operators.

### Modern C++

Since C++11, the use of new and delete, is considered confined to library writers.  As the use of `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` manage the `new` `delete` lifecycle for you, so you can focus on the problem at hand.